# How to create a new component in Angular 4 using CLI

Tags: angular-cli

In angular 2 I use

```
ng g c componentname
```

But It is not supported in Angular 4,
so I created it manually, but it shows error that it is not a module.

Comment: `ng generate component componentname`, [according to the documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#usage)

Comment: you need to import the manually created component in module.ts file

Comment: In Angular 7 also it works . `ng g c <componentname>` OR `ng generate component <Name>`

Comment: you can add component based on it's schematics and options [according to documentation](https://angular.io/cli/generate)

Answer (score 170, accepted):

In Angular4 this will work the same. If you get an error I think your problem is somewhere else.

In command prompt type

> ng generate component YOURCOMPONENTNAME

There are even shorthands for this: the commands `generate` can be used as `g` and `component` as `c`:

> ng g c YOURCOMPONENTNAME

you can use `ng --help`, `ng g --help` or `ng g c --help` for the docs.

Ofcourse rename YOURCOMPONENTNAME to the name you would like to use.

> [Docs:](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#generating-components-directives-pipes-and-services) angular-cli will add reference to components, directives and pipes automatically in the app.module.ts.

**Update: This still functions in Angular version 8.**

Comment: I am getting this error-----------installing component
Error locating module for declaration
        SilentError: No module files found

Comment: I am wondering, is there any command available to remove created component  including it's reference app module?

Comment: @pankysharma No there is no command in Angular CLI to remove a component, but if you want to recreate the component with different options; you can use the `--force` (shorthand: -f) option to override files.

Comment: "ng g c employees" worked for me. I was using a '$' before 'ng' like '$ng g c employees' which was creating issue in this case.

Comment: If you don't need the test file(.spec.ts) for your new component, add argument --skipTests to your command.

Answer (score 39):

Generating and serving an Angular project via a development server -

First go to your Project Directory and the type the below -

```
ng new my-app
cd my-app
ng generate component User (or) ng g c user 
ng serve
```

Here “**D:\Angular\my-app>**” is my Angular application Project Directory and the “**User**” is the name of component.

The commonds looks like -

```
D:\Angular\my-app>ng g component User
  create src/app/user/user.component.html (23 bytes)
  create src/app/user/user.component.spec.ts (614 bytes)
  create src/app/user/user.component.ts (261 bytes)
  create src/app/user/user.component.css (0 bytes)
  update src/app/app.module.ts (586 bytes)
```

Answer (score 33):

1) first go to your Project Directory

2) then Run below Command in terminal.

```
ng generate component componentname
```

**OR**

```
ng g component componentname
```

3) after that you will see output like this,

```
create src/app/test/componentname.component.css (0 bytes)
create src/app/test/componentname.component.html (23 bytes)
create src/app/test/componentname.component.spec.ts (614 bytes)
create src/app/test/componentname.component.ts (261 bytes)
update src/app/app.module.ts (1087 bytes)
```

Answer (score 15):

```
ng g component componentname
```

It generates the component and adds the component to module declarations.

when creating component manually , you should add the component in declaration of the module like this :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    yourCommaSeparatedModules
    ],
  declarations: [
    yourCommaSeparatedComponents
  ]
})
export class yourModule { }
```

Answer (score 14):

If you want to create new component without `.spec` file, you can use

```
ng g c component-name --spec false
```

You can find these options using `ng g c --help`

Answer (score 13):

**For creating component under certain folder**

```
ng g c employee/create-employee --skipTests=false --flat=true
```

This line will create a folder name 'employee', underneath that it creates a 'create-employee' component.

**without creating any folder**

```
ng g c create-employee --skipTests=false --flat=true
```

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you are in your project directory in the CMD line

```
    ng g component componentName
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ng g c componentname
```

It will create the following 4 files:

1. `componentname.css`
2. `componentname.html`
3. `componentname.spec.ts`
4. `componentname.ts`

Answer (score 3):

ng generate component component_name was not working in my case because instead of using 'app' as project folder name, I renamed it to something else.
I again changed it to app.
Now, it is working fine

Answer (score 3):

```
ng g c COMPONENTNAME
```

this command use  for generating component using terminal this i use in angular2.

> g for generate c for component

Answer (score 2):

In my case i happen to have another `.angular-cli.json` file in my `src` folder. Removing it solved the problem. Hope it helps

`angular 4.1.1` 
`angular-cli 1.0.1`

Answer (score 2):

```
ng g component component name
```

before you type this commend check you will be in your project directive path

Answer (score 2):

ng g c --dry-run so you can see what you are about to do before you actually do it will save some frustration.  Just shows you what it is going to do without actually doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You should be in the `src/app` folder of your angular-cli project on command line. For example:

```
D:\angular2-cli\first-app\src\app> ng generate component test
```

Only then it will generate your component.

Answer (score 2):

go to your project directory in CMD, and run the following commands. You can use the visual studio code terminal also.

`ng generate component "component_name"`

**OR**

`ng g c "component_name"`

a new folder with `"component_name"` will be created

> component_name/component_name.component.html
> component_name/component_name.component.spec.ts
> component_name/component_name.component.ts
> component_name/component_name.component.css

new component will be Automatically added module.

you can avoid creating spec file by following command

`ng g c "component_name" --nospec`

Answer (score 2):

Go to your project directory in CMD, run the following code.

```
ng g c componentname
```

A folder will be created in the component name. inside that, you can find four files such as HTML, CSS, spec.ts & ts.

And you should not rename any of the files.

Answer (score 1):

Did you update the angular-cli to latest version? or did you try updating node or npm or typescript? this issue comes because of versions like angular/typescript/node. If you are updating the cli, use this link here.
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update

Answer (score 1):

`ng g c COMPONENTNAME` should work, if your are getting module not found exception then try these things-

1. Check your project directory.
2. If you are using visual studio code then reload it or reopen your project in it.

Answer (score 1):

go to your angular project folder and open the command promt an type "ng g component header"
where header is the new component that you want to create.As default the header component will be created inside the app component.You can create components inside a component .For example if you want to create a component inside he header that we made above then type"ng g component header/menu". This will create a menu component inside the header component

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project location in Specified Folder

```
C:\Angular6\sample>
```

Here you can type the command

```
C:\Angular6\sample>ng g c users
```

Here g means generate , c means component ,users is the component name

it will generate the 4 files

```
users.component.html,
users.component.spec.ts,
users.component.ts,
users.component.css
```

Answer (score 1):

Step1:

**Get into Project Directory!**(cd into created app).

Step2:

**Type in the following command and run!**

`ng generate component [componentname]`

- **Add the name of component you want to generate in the [componentname] section.**

**OR**

`ng generate c [componentname]`

- **Add name of component you want to generate in the [componentname] section.**

**Both will work**

For reference checkout this section of Angular Documentation!

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1

For reference also checkout the link to Angular Cli on github!

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-component

Answer (score 1):

```
ng generate component componentName.
```

It will automatically import the component in module.ts

Answer (score 1):

There are mainly two ways to generate new component in Angular,
    using `ng g c <component_name>` , another way is that using `ng generate component <component_name>`. using one  of these commands new component can be generated.

Answer (score 1):

cd to your project and run,

```
> ng generate component "componentname"
ex: ng generate component shopping-cart
```

OR

```
> ng g c shopping-cart
```

(This will create new folder under "app" folder with name "shopping-cart" and create .html,.ts, .css. specs files.)

If you do not want to generate .spec file

```
> ng g c shopping-cart --skipTests true
```

If you want to create component in any specific folder under "app"

```
> ng g c ecommerce/shopping-cart
```

(you will get folder structure "app/ecommerce/shopping-cart")

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to upgrade the latest angular cli using this command.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Then if you run `ng g c componentName`, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

if you want that component not appears in one folder.

```
ng g c NameComponent --flat
```