# Problem when generating the component in Angular

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript, components, angular-components

[image: component]

I am facing this issue, I am unable to generate the component in angular, I tried deleting node-modules, tried uninstalling angular cli, again installed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your terminal recognize command differently?
I see you have opened files ng,g,c and product-detail - are they opened/created after invoking this command?

Check here btw [How to create a new component in Angular 4 using CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44151427/how-to-create-a-new-component-in-angular-4-using-cli)

Comment: When I hit the command for new components. its get created

Comment: well thats not good(
make sure your terminal recognize "ng" as an angular cli. 
try ng help
ng generate --help
https://angular.io/cli#basic-workflow

Comment: btw how did you install cli?

Comment: npm install @angular/cli

Comment: oh try to add flag -g to make it global

Comment: When I run ng help command its generating the help file, when I run the ng generate --help its generating the generate file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253009/discussion-between-ajay-singh-and-eugene-porodko).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have *misconfigured* something in the project, if you have not made much progress in the project I recommend the following (because it is not normal for you to have this type of problem)

**First of all, sometimes VSC bugs, I close and open and everything is fine.**
If it does not work:

1. Uninstall Angular
2. Install Angular
3. Remember if the packages are installed (NPM)
4. ng generate component product-detail or ng g c product-detail
5. Sometimes the solution to complex problems requires trying different ways to solve it, I hope this type of quick solution will help you.

> remember: Download the extensions for angular, they will help you a
> lot. (Tell me how it's going)